# C++ Opencv: Is there a way to get the depth of a node?

Tags: c++, opencv, tree, nodes

It seems to me that a basic attribute of a node in a tree should be it's depth. I am implementing a Random Forest in C++ using OpenCV3.0, and I would like to access the depths of each individual trees. So far, I have the root nodes of each tree and I would just like the depth of each one. However, looking at the OpenCV documentation, there does not seem to be a simple way to do this. Am I missing something here, or do I really have to manually find the depth of the tree by looping through the children until there are no more children?

Answer (score 0):

After a brief look at the code, I would agree that there seems to be no obvious, pre-implemented way to get the exact depth of your trees.  My guess is, that function is not a priority for most people who are interested in this kind of machine learning, so they haven't bothered.

So, yes, go ahead and write your own.